# add a print button inside a joomla article

Tags: joomla, printing, module

I have a module with a load position in a joomla page. Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to print the page and also the module. I've inserted a link with the following parameter but that didn't work either:

index.php/our-cars/loan-calculator?tmpl=component&format=pdf

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Joomla default print and email button will be available on all article pages.
If you are disable those buttons then simply enable it.

```
Content menu -> article - > Options on tootlbar
```

First tab article have option for `Show Print Icon` just enable it.

this option will enable the print button for your all articles, In joomla 1.7 its will not work . If you are using Joomla 1.7 or do not need the print icon for all articles then follow the steps.

Go to menu manager and which article is needs print icon just go to that menu and choose article options from right side you can find a same options here too.

Hope its helps..